# how to do auto login in wordpress with registration?

Tags: wordpress, autologin

I am creating a website with WordPress. I want to do autologin with URL parameter. That is working fine but if user does not exist then I want to insert and then do auto login.

```
function process_demo_login(){
    if(isset($_GET['autologin']) && !is_user_logged_in()){
        $username=$_GET['autologin'];
        $password='demo';
        $user = wp_authenticate($username, $password);
        $secure_cookie = '';
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true, $secure_cookie);
        do_action('wp_login', $username);
        wp_redirect(home_url());
    }       
}

add_action('plugins_loaded','process_demo_login');
```

Comment: How you auto-login should work? What about the security?

Comment: website is on local ip..so no problem of security

Comment: did you check wp_create_user? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user

Comment: i have used wp_create_user.But i want action to be perform together..Suppose i sent a url with username if username is exsits then it will login automatically and redirect to homepage and if username is not exists then it should create user and then login and redirect to homepge..

Comment: check before`wp_authenticate` if it exists and if not, create a new one. some functions like `username_exists` can help.

Comment: and if you just want to solve this problem, i recommend you to check the plugins repository. I've found 2 plugins for auto-login with custom link that may help you.